# Write in NodeJs buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a JS client and C# server connection.

The connection is going well. The problem occurs when I want to send a buffer from the JS client to the C# server.

For the buffer to be processed by my server, the buffer must have a particular structure: A header encoded on 18 bytes, followed by the message.

Buffer contains:

1. Size of the message on 8 bytes
2. Message ID on 8 bytes
3. Message type on 2 bytes

In a previous version I used a C # client to send this buffer. I proceed like this:

```
//Header parameters
ulong ID = ulong.MaxValue;
ushort type = 0;

//Message
string message = "This is the message";
byte[] encodedMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

//Encoding the header and add header to buffer
byte[] buffer = new byte[encodedMessage.Length + 18];
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(encodedMessage.LongLength + 18), 0, buffer, 0, 8);
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes(ID), 0, buffer, 8, 8);
Array.Copy(BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)type), 0, buffer, 16, 2);

//Adding the message to the buffer
Array.Copy(encodedMessage, 0, buffer, 18, encodedMessage.Length);
```

Header informations are converted with the C# BitConverter.GetBytes() function.

I would like to do the same in NodeJs

I did this:

```
var msg = "This is the message"

var size = 18 + msg.length

var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(size)
var buf = Buffer.from(buffer);

// Writting the header
buf.write(str(size-18),0,8) // Write the message size
buf.write("123456",8,8) // Write the id
buf.write("0",16,2) // Write the message type

//Adding the message to the buffer
buf.write(msg,18,msg.length)
```

But in this way the header is not converted to a bit like the C # function above.

Is there a method to do this in nodejs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Buffer.alloc`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_alloc_size_fill_encoding) to initialize the header buffer with a length of 18 bytes. Then write the data with something like this and finally concat the header buffer with the content buffer:

```
const content = "This is the message";
const headerBuffer = Buffer.alloc(18);
headerBuffer.write(Buffer.from(content, 'ascii').byteLength.toString(), 0, 8);
headerBuffer.write("1234", 8, 8);
headerBuffer.write("0", 16, 2);
const contentBuffer = Buffer.from(content, 'ascii');
const result = Buffer.concat([headerBuffer, contentBuffer]);
```

Writing this buffer to a file and displaying it with `hexdump` results in:

```
$ hexdump -C tmp 
00000000  31 39 00 00 00 00 00 00  31 32 33 34 00 00 00 00  |19......1234....|
00000010  30 00 54 68 69 73 20 69  73 20 74 68 65 20 6d 65  |0.This is the me|
00000020  73 73 61 67 65                                    |ssage|
00000025
```

Comment: If he only wants to write 18 bytes why allocate 18423 bytes?

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, but I don't understand why you multiply the size by 18 ?
The buffer contains a header of size 18 and a text message of maximum size of 1024

Answer (score 0):

You can allocate the amount of bytes fro a buffer using `Buffer.alloc` method. The method takes an integer that will indicate the length of the buffer. If you create a buffer with the **new** keyword then you are using `Buffer.allocUnsafe` method under the hood so, therefore it recommended to create buffers without new keyword. With that said here is the solution I came up with

```
const msg = 'This is a message'
const buffer = Buffer.alloc(18)
let bytesWritten = 0;

// Write the first 8 bytes
bytesWritten += buffer.write(msg, 0, 8)
console.log('I wrote ',bytesWritten,' bytes');
// Write the next 8 bytes
bytesWritten += buffer.write(msg, (buffer.length - bytesWritten), 8);
console.log('I have now written ',bytesWritten,' bytes');
// Write the remaining 2 bytes
buffer.write(msg, (buffer.length - bytesWritten), 2);
```